# Проблема с PlaySoundA

Tags: c++, c, winapi, аудио

Воспроизвожу звук так:

```cpp
PlaySound( "C:\\snd.wav" , NULL , SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC );
```

В итоге если звук нужно воспроизвести несколько раз, при каждом воспроизведении старый звук прекращается не доиграв до конца.

Как можно сделать чтобы звуки проигрывались, при этом не завершая предыдущий пока он сам по себе не доиграет?

Comment: На сколько я помню там функция возвращает булю при выполнении тру если прервалось фолс

Comment: и как сделать чтобы она не прерывалась ?

Comment: ну пока функция не вернет true не запускать следующую. Оберните в цикл какой нибудь.

Comment: тогда они не будут накладываться друг на друга

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, проблему невозможно решить, или нужно делать очень дикие костыли.

Сделал проще, подключил библиотеку BASS и все работает как нужно, правда уже без WinAPI функции.

Answer (score 2):

Первый способ:
Вызывать `PlaySound` с флагом `SND_SYNC` в цикле столько раз, сколько надо.

```
int main() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        BOOL ret = PlaySound(L"c:\\Windows\\media\\Alarm01.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_SYNC | SND_NOSTOP);

        if (ret != TRUE)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error playing sound :(" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Минус такого способа в блокирующем вызове PlaySound, пока проигрывание звука не завершится функция не вернет управление. Можно поместить данный код в поток и управлять

Второй:
Можно вызвать `PlaySound` с флагом `SND_LOOP`

```
int main() 
{
    BOOL ret = PlaySound(L"c:\\Windows\\media\\Alarm01.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC | SND_LOOP);

    if (ret != TRUE)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error playing sound :(" << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");

    // Stop playing
    PlaySound(NULL, NULL, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Минус - непонятно как контролировать, сколько раз проигрался звук.

Comment: Сейчас делаю так
```void playsound( const char* sound_path )
{
 PlaySound( sound_path , NULL , SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC );
}

const char* path = "C:\\snd.wav";
  CreateThread( 0 , 0 , LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE( playsound ) , LPVOID(path) , 0 , 0 );
```

В итоге новый звук завершает старый.

Comment: @33cc00, функция playsound не умеет микшировать звуки, если я правльно помню, то даже несколько потоков будут прерывать друг друга, вам надо смотреть в сторону MCI

Comment: если проигрывать через SND_MEMORY, то тогда все хорошо, но в этом случае нельзя быстро заменять звук

Answer (score 2):

PlaySound - самый примитивный из звуковых API в Windows, кроме того, устаревший лет 10 назад. Параллельное воспроизведение он действительно не поддерживает (видимо, для отслеживания состояния воспроизведения используется какой-то глобальный объект, который каждый раз сбрасывается). PlaySound нормально использовать для воспроизведения коротких звуков из ресурсов или системных звуков, но для файлов лучше взять что-то более продвинутое, хотя бы [DirectShow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directshow/how-to-play-a-file):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Dshow.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment( lib, "winmm.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "Strmiids.lib" )

void PlaySoundNew_Impl(const TCHAR* file){ //реализация воспроизведения файла с использованием DirectShow

    IGraphBuilder *pGraph = NULL;
    IMediaControl *pControl = NULL;
    IMediaEvent   *pEvent = NULL;       

    // Create the filter graph manager and query for interfaces.
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                        IID_IGraphBuilder, (void **)&pGraph);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("ERROR - Could not create the Filter Graph Manager.");
        return;
    }

    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&pControl);
    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaEvent, (void **)&pEvent);

    // Build the graph. 
    hr = pGraph->RenderFile(file, NULL);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Run the graph.
        hr = pControl->Run();
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Wait for completion.
            long evCode;
            pEvent->WaitForCompletion(INFINITE, &evCode);                       
        }
    }
    else printf("RenderFile error 0x%x",(UINT)hr);

    pControl->Release();
    pEvent->Release();
    pGraph->Release();
}

DWORD WINAPI PlaySoundNew_ThreadProc(LPVOID lpThreadParameter){ //функция для фонового потока

    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL); //для фонового потока также нужна инициализация COM
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("ERROR - Could not initialize COM library");
        return 1;
    }

    const TCHAR* file = (const TCHAR*)lpThreadParameter;
    PlaySoundNew_Impl(file);

    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}

void PlaySoundNew(const TCHAR* file, bool async){ //воспроизведение файла через DirectShow

    if( async == FALSE){ 
        PlaySoundNew_Impl(file); //синхронно        
    }
    else{ 
        CreateThread(NULL,0,PlaySoundNew_ThreadProc,(LPVOID)file,0,NULL); //асинхронно
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("ERROR - Could not initialize COM library");
        return 1;
    }

    PlaySoundNew(L"C:\\Music\\Sound1.wav", true);
    Sleep(2000);
    PlaySoundNew(L"C:\\Music\\Sound2.wav", true);   

    getchar();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```